# Displaying Microsoft Office Document(word, excel etc) in JSF Page or HTML

Tags: java, html, jsf, ms-office

I got to display documents in web page instead download it. There are HTML 5 components(object, iframe) for pdf but  office document. Is there a way to display Word, Excel etc. documents on JSF page or HTML.

Comment: There is no such thing a "jsf" page. There is only HTML. JSF is on the server.

Comment: @Diodeus, You missed the point, it was not what I tried to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers cannot natively display Microsoft Office documents.

The solution is usually to generate them as PDFs on the server-side, then allow the user to view them (if that have the PDF plugin) or download the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with OpenXML documents (.docx, etc...) you can use an XML Parser to obtain the content and display it as you wish.